# How to post into the MongoDb collection using postman

Tags: json, mongodb, post, asp.net-web-api, postman

I am trying to insert data into the MongoDb collection using postman. How would I approach this; hardcoding the data in JSON format works, but I want to be able to **insert using postman in JSON format.**

This is the code that allowed me to enter directly, using the post function in postman, with no input:

```
    public async void Insert([FromBody]string value)
    {
        var client = new MongoClient();
        var dbs = client.GetDatabase("test");
        var collection = dbs.GetCollection<BsonDocument>                                                          ("restaurants");

        BsonArray dataFields = new BsonArray { new BsonDocument { 
         { "ID" , ObjectId.GenerateNewId()}, { "_id", ""}, } };

        var document = new BsonDocument
          {

        {"borough",value },
        {"cuisine","Korean"},

        {"name","Bellaa"},    
        {"restaurant_id","143155"}

        };
    await collection.InsertOneAsync(document);

    }
```

Comment: I'd like to recommend Advanced REST Client extension for Chrome instead of Postman. I had similar problems trying to test CRUD routes with MongoDB using Postman until I finally gave up and went looking for alternatives. AVC worked like a charm and would've saved much time debugging had I chosen it first. Disclaimer: I am in no way affiliated with AVC. I just like the product, the interface and think it just does its job. Hope that helps someone save some time testing their REST routes.

Answer (score 2):

You can send it as raw data. You will set the post type to `application/json`.

[image]

This comes From the [docs](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/requests).

Comment: yes that is the basics but currently doing so does not add the information to the collection, gives me errors. I need to find out the code that will let me do that. 

this is the error:

{
  "Message": "The request entity's media type 'text/plain' is not supported for this resource.",
  "ExceptionMessage": "No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'String' from content with media type 'text/plain'.",
  "ExceptionType": "System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException",

Comment: simply inserting the JSON data works in the default methods but to connect to the MongoDB seems to require similar codes to what I posted.